# Is it okay to write $[0,\infty]$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, interval-arithmetic

In my tuition school, a teacher wrote $[0, \infty]$ and i asked him if it is ever possible to write $\infty]$. He sternly replied not to question about silly things and focus on what is being taught. I thought if it was every possible and later asked my physics teacher about it, and he gave me a nice answer... He told that there is a professor in Calcutta University and a student had asked him the similar question i asked, and he had replied that it is not incorrect. I do not know why, but is there a mathematical reasoning, or just an intuition, or cant it be written at all? Which is more accurate(correct): $[0, \infty)$ or $[0,\infty]$?

Comment: They simply denote different things. $[0,\infty)$ is the set of non-negative real numbers. $[0,\infty]$ is the set of non-negative real numbers *and* $\infty$ (formally just a new symbol which is defined to be greater than every real number, i.e. as in the extended real line).

Comment: Was your tuition school teacher meaning to include $\infty$ in the set? If so, he should use $\infty]$. If not, he should use $\infty)$. For example, if the context was to denote the non-negative reals ($\{ x\in \Bbb{R} : x \ge 0\}$), then he should use $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Here is a useful link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

Comment: @MinusOne-TwelfthHe was simply teaching relations and functions and set theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure is, and the meaning is exactly as you'd expect: since it's an interval descriptor that ends with a "$]$", then it means that it includes its right endpoint, which means it includes

$$\infty$$

i.e. $\infty \in [0, \infty]$. Now you may think that weird, because most likely you were taught that "$\infty$" is just some "notational symbol" or something "used with limits" and "not really a 'number'". This is, in fact, half true and half not true. It is a notational symbol alright, but it is *also* an object that, while not a *real* number, is nonetheless something else called an "extended real number" and lives in a space called the "extended real number line".

The extended real number line is just the usual reals together with two elements $\infty$ and $-\infty$ added to them:

$$\mathbb{R}_\mathrm{ext} := \mathbb{R} \cup \{ -\infty, \infty \}$$

and we extend the ordering operation $\le$ (a Boolean-valued function) on the real numbers by asserting

$$[-\infty \le x \le \infty] = \mathrm{True}$$

for every *extended* real number $x$, and $\mathrm{False}$ otherwise (while also retaining the usual order for ordinary reals, of course!). You should check that this also implies $-\infty < \infty$. Intuitively, we "cap" the "ends" of the real number line with the two elements, in the obvious fashion. Now $[0, \infty]$ is a proper *extended* real interval, but is *not* a *real* interval.

And that last point is important - because while this construction is *100% mathematically kosher*, you have to *be careful* when working with $\infty$ and not to mis-apply rules from the reals that don't apply to it. For example, $\infty - \infty$ is *undefined*, and you can't, thus, subtract $\infty$ from both sides of an expression and cancel it out. This should make sense to you given the usage in limits, where when this form appears, it signals that you have to take a more clever approach to examining your limit problem. Adding $\infty$ into play as a "real" number doesn't change that because it doesn't work like real numbers do. One thus also has to be careful *not to confuse* things defined in $\mathbb{R}$ with things defined in $\mathbb{R}_\mathrm{ext}$. Paying attention to domains *is very important*.

Answer (score 0):

This is used in measure theory. A measure is a function that takes subsets of a given set and assigns each one of them a number in $[0, \infty]$. So not only is it allowed, it's encouraged.

And your teacher was wrong for accusing you of asking a silly question.